# Getting multiple checkbox POST values into django view

Tags: django

By using django view, I need to delete rows in my database based on list of checkboxes selected  from html template

`index.html`:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'mul_delete' %}">
{% csrf_token %}        
<button type="sumbit" name="del" id="del">Delete</button>
{% for smail in form1 %}
<input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check" class="check" value="{{smail.id}}"/>
</form>
```

`view.py`:

```
def mul_delete(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        chk = request.POST.getlist('check')
        print(chk)

    return redirect('/form1')
```

[1,2,3,4]

Comment: so what is the problem? you are getting the id's as you need

Comment: Is you checkbox working properly? or do you need help in that?

Answer (score 0):

If You're getting **Id's** from the radio button then just simply pass the id to query for its extraction and then deletion.

```
def mul_delete(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        chk = request.POST.getlist('check')
        print(chk)
    Model.objects.filter(id=chk).delete()     #<--- user filter or get
    return redirect('/form1')
```

---

If you're trying to delete multiple objects then you can pass all the id's as a list to query set which will filter all of them and hence delete them.

```
Model.objects.filter(id__in=list_var).delete()     #<--- user filter only
```